# Register hotkey with only modifiers in Linux

Tags: linux, x11, hotkeys

I'm using [this sample](https://jnativehook.googlecode.com/svn/branches/test_code/linux/XGrabKey.c) to set hotkey in my program in Linux X11 graphic system. The problem is i don't understand how to set hotkey combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, i.e. without any key, only modifers. I'm trying like this:

```
KeyCode key = XKeysymToKeycode(display, 0); //no key code
XGrabKey(display, key, ControlMask | ShiftMask, grabWin, true, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
```

But it's not working. However, it is working like this (kind of):

```
 KeyCode key = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Alt_L); //Alt key
 XGrabKey(display, key, ControlMask, grabWin, true, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
```

I don't like this solution, because:

1. Logically wrong
2. It's only fires when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed, not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, i.e. pressing order is important
3. It's blocking all other combinations in windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749444/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-consuming-them-in-x11-keyboard-hooking). Grabs are for hotkeys you consume; if you want to only listen without consuming events, you need something else.