# Grabbing any keypress in X11

Tags: x11

I'm trying to implement a simple X11 key grabber in C for window switching with Alt-Tab etc. I can use the function *XSelectInput* to handle keyboard events for a specific window:

```
XSelectInput(display, window, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask);
```

How can I receive "global" keyboard events regardless of which window is focused?

Comment: Take a look at my c program of hooking mouse and keyboard globally in X11 [link](https://github.com/BladeMight/Mahou.linux/blob/master/X11-Hooks.c).

Comment: Also, check the source code for `xev`: http://xev.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1:1.0.2-0ubuntu1/xev_8c-source.html `xev` will show *all* X events, including every key press event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `XGrabKey`. This function is specifically designed for implementing hotkeys.

When the desired key combination is pressed, you get the event no matter what, and no other window gets the event.

Comment: what if you want to be notified but not steal it from other clients? There's the alternative of following the focussed window without grabbing but this approach seems very unreliable

Comment: @phil294 [here you are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749444/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-consuming-them-in-x11-keyboard-hooking)