# Can SDL2 capture global keystrokes?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I'm trying to make simple background/console tool in **C++** which would listen to my keystrokes. `SDL_PollEvent` nor `SDL_GetKeyboardState` listens when foreign window is focused. Question is, if it is possible to do this with **SDL2** or do I need to use other multi-platform library or should I just do it from scratch per OS?

**Note:**
Right now I want to use this tool on linux and I managed to find libX11 solution: [Listening to keyboard events without consuming them in X11 - Keyboard hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749444/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-consuming-them-in-x11-keyboard-hooking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that global keystroke capture is in scope for SDL.

You'll have to use some other platform-specific means. For Linux and Unix, libX11 is one of the options, another would be to use `/dev/input/event#` (see e.g. [here for examples](https://thehackerdiary.wordpress.com/2017/04/21/exploring-devinput-1/)).